# docker find container by pid of inside process

Tags: docker

I have docker containers. Inside them launched a process. 
**From the host machine** the command `top` outputs pid of all processes launched in within containers.

How can I find a container in which the process with this PID is running?

Thank you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Thank you @Alex Past and @Stanislav for the help. But I did not get full answers for me. I combined them.
In summary I has got next.

First

```
pstree -sg <PID>
```

where PID is the process's PID from the command `top`

In output I am getting parent PID for the systemd parent process. This PID is docker container's PID.

After I execute

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}' | grep "^%PID%"
```

where *%PID%* is this parent PID.

In result I have docker's *CONTAINER ID*.

That's what I wanted

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
 docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}' | grep "%PID%"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find all parents for this process:

```
pstree -sg <PID>
```

This chain will be contains the container

Answer (score 2):

I kinda combined all of these and wrote this two liner. Hopefully useful to someone.

```
#!/bin/bash
SCAN_PID=`pstree -sg $1 |  head -n 1 | grep -Po 'shim\([0-9]+\)---[a-z]+\(\K[^)]*'`
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}' | grep "^${SCAN_PID},"
```

First line finds the container entry script and feeds it to the docker inspect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `exec` against each running container checking if the pid exists. Of course the same process id could exists in more than one container. Here is a small bash script that search for a running process based on the supplied pid in each container:

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(docker ps -q); do
  status=`docker exec $container ls /proc/$1 2>/dev/null`
  if [ ! -z "$status" ]; then
    name=`docker ps --filter ID=$container --format "{{.Names}}"`
    echo "PID: $1 found in $container ($name)"
    break;
  fi
done;
```

For example:

```
./find-process.sh 1
```

Comment: so you always `docker exec` in the container 7dd276808aec? This looks bogus.

Comment: @user2915097 - Oops my bad I'll update. Of course you need to exec into every running container and check if the `/proc/<pid>` directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the parent processes of the target process using `ps -o ppid=` and at each step check if the PID of the parent matches one of the containers.

```
#!/bin/bash

targetpid=$1
parentpid=0

while [ $parentpid != 1 ]; do
    parentpid=$(ps -o ppid= $targetpid)
    docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}' | grep "^$parentpid"
    targetpid="$parentpid"
done
```