# docker show pid of container processes, from container perspective, without ps

Tags: docker

I need to identify the pid of a process inside a container, from the container's perspective (so I can send it a signal from within the container, specifically `SIGQUIT` so I can get a thread dump). The process is *not* the root process of the container, so I cannot `docker kill`. The container shell does not provide `ps`, so I cannot use the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911232/docker-find-container-by-pid-of-inside-process). `docker top` shows me pids from the *host's* perspective, not the container's. What other avenues do I have to get the information I need?

Comment: `ps` itself reads from `/proc`. You can of course inspect that directory tree without using it with just standard UNIX tools. For example, `readlink /proc/*/exe` will list you the executables that each process has invoked.

Comment: that said, the host is perfectly capable of telling what PIDs look like inside a container; you don't need to step fully inside the container to do that, but you _can_.

Comment: Other options include taking on the container's process namespace while keeping the host's filesystem namespace, f/e, so you can run the host's copy of `ps` but see the container's view of processes. To manipulate namespaces individually, see `nsenter`.

Comment: How do I get the host to tell me what the pids inside the container are? My Google searching has not revealed that information.

Comment: Sorry -- not answering myself because I don't currently run Docker so I can't test anything firsthand.

Comment: That said, if I needed an answer, I'd be looking at [the procfs docs](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/proc.html). It's all in there somewhere.

Comment: (and note how https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html specifies that `/proc/<pid>/ns/pid` is the identifier for a namespace you can give to nsenter to switch a new process -- like a copy of `ps` started from the host -- into the same namespace the process with host PID `<pid>` is using).

Comment: Inside the container, the main container process will always have pid 1, which among other things means its default signal handling if different.  If that container has launched child processes, it should get back their (container-space) pids as the response from fork(2) or similar; this is the same mechanism as without Docker.

Comment: Yeah, the parent process _could_ be helpfully capturing the child pid, but I'd hope for a solution that does not require that. (After asking the question I was reminded that `/proc` on the container can tell me what the pid is as well, which I suppose will do in a pinch, but I'm hoping to accept an answer that indicates "How do I get the host to tell me what the pids inside the container are?")